# Android Studio SQLite Database Unable to find on Android Device Monitor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, mobile-development

I'm trying to create a database to store data entered on the journal app I'm developing at the moment, but I came across an small issue where I try to see if the database is created, but it doesn't show when I look on Android Device Monitor > data > data > database folders.

What exactly am I missing on my code?

```
     public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    //Constants for db name and version
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Constants for identifying table and columns
    public static final String TABLE_NOTES = "notes";
    public static final String NOTE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NOTE_TEXT = "noteText";
    public static final String NOTE_CREATED = "noteCreated";

    //SQL to create table
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES + " (" +
                    NOTE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    NOTE_TEXT + " TEXT, " +
                    NOTE_CREATED + " TEXT default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" +
                    ")";

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

---

```
     public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        DBOpenHelper helper = new DBOpenHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Have you inserted any data? It's not until data is inserted that the database is actually saved to the file. Additionally the path will include the package.

Comment: I haven't inserted any data, I'm just looking to see if the code i wrote to create the database is being made when looking through android device monitor.

Comment: You could try a query on the table e.g. `Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NOTES",null);`. The cursor count (`csr.getCount()`) would return an integer with a value of 0. However, just running the query should work or fail depending on the DB status. Perhaps include include this as a method in DBOpenHelper and invoke from HomeActivity. However I don't think this would save the database to a file. although it may reassure you that the database exists (in memory). Best way though would be to insert some data, then the physical file will exist.